# how I can reach the next value of a linked list?

Tags: javascript, oop, properties, linked-list, null

I am trying to write a linked list in javascript. I have a class, a constructor and an addtoLast function which provides connection between each other.

But in addtoLast function, I can't reach "**next**" property of my any object.

It says

> Cannot create property 'next' on number 'x'

(x as a first value and head of linked list)

The codes are:

```js
class LinkedList
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.head=[];
        this.next=null;
        this.length=0;
    }

    addtoLast(value)
    {
        if(this.head==null)
        {
            this.head=value;
            this.length++;
        }
        else
        {
            let now=this.head;
            let newNode=value;

            while(now.next!=null)
            now=now.next;

            now.next=newNode;   //it gives that error
            newNode.next=null;  //and it gives too!
            this.length++;
        }  
    }
}

//and my main function is:

let example = new LinkedList();
example.head = 3;
example.addtoLast(9);
document.write(example);
```

I will be thankful for any comment :)

Comment: `let newNode=value;` what should this do? And you donst seem to understand linked lists

Comment: `now is an integer`, you can't assign the `next` property to an integer, as the error says. Instead, wrap the integer in a node object `{ value: now, next: ... }`

Comment: you declared `this.head=[]`, your list has multiple heads?

Comment: newNode is just a variable for the value. we use it for reaching to the next value. so we can't say `value.next`  this is what I meant. @JonasW.

Comment: Do you recommend to me do that constructor must have "node part" @caesay

Comment: `this.head=[]` means values between `[` and  `]` are object of head. isn't it true? @Sphinx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed below issues:

1. `this.head`: it should not be one array (otherwise the list has multiple heads), it should be one object, and should be initialized with null or `{value:'',next:null}`.
2. `let newNode={'value':value, 'next':null};` follow same rules as `this.head`.
3. change `example.head = 3;` to `example.head = {'value':3, 'next':null};`
   **PS**: but it will cause the length of the list is wrong.
4. removed `this.next=null`, next should be one attribute of each node.
   Below is one working sample.

```js
class LinkedList
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.head=null;
        //this.next=null;
        this.length=0;
    }

    addtoLast(value)
    {
        if(!this.head)
        {
            this.head={'value':value, 'next':null};
            this.length++;
        }
        else
        {
            let now=this.head;
            let newNode={'value':value, 'next':null};

            while(now.next!=null)
            now=now.next;

            now.next=newNode;   //it gives that error
            newNode.next=null;  //and it gives too!
            this.length++;
        }  
    }
}

//and my main function is:

let example = new LinkedList();
//example.head = {'value':3, 'next':null};
example.addtoLast(3);
example.addtoLast(9);
example.addtoLast(10);
console.log(example);
document.write(example);
```

Comment: then because of `let newNode={'value':value, 'next':null};` this line `newNode.next=null;` is not necessary. Thank you a lot @Sphinx